# having trouble with Three.js .Json Loader (importing 3d models)

Tags: three.js

This is a skull i found on clara.io , i downloaded the .obj, and uploaded into the three.js editor, and proceeded to export it as Json.. Now I have been trying to add it to some of the three.js examples. What am I doing wrong. I notice the examples have different scripts linked, but most tutorials show people only linking the build. I love this stuff so much, I really wanna learn...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>three.js canvas - panorama fisheye demo</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no,         minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">

       <style>
        body {
            background-color: rgb(200,200,200);
            margin: 0px;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        #info {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px; width: 100%;
            color: #ffffff;
            padding: 5px;
            font-family:Monospace;
            font-size:13px;
            font-weight: bold;
            text-align:center;
        }

        a {
            color: #ffffff;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="container"></div>
    <div id="info"><a href="http://threejs.org" target="_blank">three.js</a> - panorama fisheye demo. cubemap by <a href="http://www.zfight.com/" target="_blank">Jochum Skoglund</a>. (mousewheel: change fov)</div>

    <script src="../build/three.js"></script>

    <script src="js/renderers/Projector.js"></script>
    <script src="js/renderers/CanvasRenderer.js"></script>

    <script>

        var camera, scene, renderer;

        var texture_placeholder,
        isUserInteracting = false,
        onMouseDownMouseX = 0, onMouseDownMouseY = 0,
        lon = 90, onMouseDownLon = 0,
        lat = 0, onMouseDownLat = 0,
        phi = 0, theta = 0,
        target = new THREE.Vector3();

        init();
        animate();

        function init() {

            var container, mesh;

            container = document.getElementById( 'container' );

            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1100 );

            scene = new THREE.Scene();

            texture_placeholder = document.createElement( 'canvas' );
            texture_placeholder.width = 128;
            texture_placeholder.height = 128;

            var context = texture_placeholder.getContext( '2d' );
            context.fillStyle = 'rgb( 200, 200, 200 )';
            context.fillRect( 0, 0, texture_placeholder.width, texture_placeholder.height );

            var materials = [

                loadTexture( 'textures/cube/skybox/px.jpg' ), // right
                loadTexture( 'textures/cube/skybox/nx.jpg' ), // left
                loadTexture( 'textures/cube/skybox/py.jpg' ), // top
                loadTexture( 'textures/cube/skybox/ny.jpg' ), // bottom
                loadTexture( 'textures/cube/skybox/pz.jpg' ), // back
                loadTexture( 'textures/cube/skybox/nz.jpg' ) // front

            ];

            mesh = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.BoxGeometry( 300, 300, 300, 7, 7, 7 ), new THREE.MultiMaterial( materials ) );
            mesh.scale.x = - 1;
            scene.add( mesh );

            for ( var i = 0, l = mesh.geometry.vertices.length; i < l; i ++ ) {

                var vertex = mesh.geometry.vertices[ i ];

                vertex.normalize();
                vertex.multiplyScalar( 550 );

            }

            var particleMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial();
            particleMaterial.map = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture ('');
            particleMaterial.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
            var itmArr = []

            var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();


            loader.load('models/json/skull.json', function (geometry) {
                for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, particleMaterial);
                    mesh.position.z = (Math.random()-Math.random())*100;
                    mesh.position.x = (Math.random()-Math.random())*100;
                    mesh.position.y = (Math.random()-Math.random())*100;
                    mesh.dir = (Math.random()-Math.random())*.01;
                    scene.add(mesh);
                    itmArr.push(mesh);
                    }
                }); 

            renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
            renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

            document.addEventListener( 'mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown, false );
            document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );
            document.addEventListener( 'mouseup', onDocumentMouseUp, false );
            document.addEventListener( 'wheel', onDocumentMouseWheel, false );

            document.addEventListener( 'touchstart', onDocumentTouchStart, false );
            document.addEventListener( 'touchmove', onDocumentTouchMove, false );

            //

            window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

        }

        function onWindowResize() {

            camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

        }

        function loadTexture( path ) {

            var texture = new THREE.Texture( texture_placeholder );
            var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture, overdraw: 0.5 } );

            var image = new Image();
            image.onload = function () {

                texture.image = this;
                texture.needsUpdate = true;

            };
            image.src = path;

            return material;

        }

        function onDocumentMouseDown( event ) {

            event.preventDefault();

            isUserInteracting = true;

            onPointerDownPointerX = event.clientX;
            onPointerDownPointerY = event.clientY;

            onPointerDownLon = lon;
            onPointerDownLat = lat;

        }

        function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {

            if ( isUserInteracting === true ) {

                lon = ( onPointerDownPointerX - event.clientX ) * 0.1 + onPointerDownLon;
                lat = ( event.clientY - onPointerDownPointerY ) * 0.1 + onPointerDownLat;

            }
        }

        function onDocumentMouseUp( event ) {

            isUserInteracting = false;

        }

        function onDocumentMouseWheel( event ) {

            camera.fov += event.deltaY * 0.05;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

        }

        function onDocumentTouchStart( event ) {

            if ( event.touches.length == 1 ) {

                event.preventDefault();

                onPointerDownPointerX = event.touches[ 0 ].pageX;
                onPointerDownPointerY = event.touches[ 0 ].pageY;

                onPointerDownLon = lon;
                onPointerDownLat = lat;

            }

        }

        function onDocumentTouchMove( event ) {

            if ( event.touches.length == 1 ) {

                event.preventDefault();

                lon = ( onPointerDownPointerX - event.touches[0].pageX ) * 0.1     + onPointerDownLon;
                lat = ( event.touches[0].pageY - onPointerDownPointerY ) * 0.1 + onPointerDownLat;

            }

        }

        function animate() {

            requestAnimationFrame( animate );
            update();

        }

        function update() {

            if ( isUserInteracting === false ) {

                lon += 0.1;

            }

            lat = Math.max( - 85, Math.min( 85, lat ) );
            phi = THREE.Math.degToRad( 90 - lat );
            theta = THREE.Math.degToRad( lon );

            target.x = 500 * Math.sin( phi ) * Math.cos( theta );
            target.y = 500 * Math.cos( phi );
            target.z = 500 * Math.sin( phi ) * Math.sin( theta );

            camera.position.copy( target ).negate();
            camera.lookAt( target );

            renderer.render( scene, camera );

        }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would suggest you take a look at the `ObjectLoader` example: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_loader_json_claraio.html Ensure that the model is in the right directory.  In case you've downloaded the three.js source, you could put your model in the `models/json/` folder and edit the example with your file name.

Comment: i have downloaded the package, the teapot won't even pop up when i copy and paste the raw, although the teapot shows up in the online example. Certain loader examples are not working from the downloaded package. Ive tried pretty much all of them, but they are blank when i start, and they all work fine on the threejs website.....

Comment: You need to take a look at https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#Manual/Getting_Started/How_to_run_things_locally